# Warning message on Insert or update

Tags: postgresql, odbc

I keep getting a message whenever I insert or update any record in any table in my database:

```
[34931.406] SQL_Statement           1  4  -1 999999999 01S02 -5      -- cursor updatability changed
```

I was wondering exactly what this message means and why I am getting it. Is it safe to ignore?
Am I supposed to react to it / do something different?

Thanks for reading

---

Just in case its necessary - 
I'm running PostgreSQL 9.1.2 on Ubuntu LTE
I'm using 32bit ODBC psqlodbc_09_01_0100 on Windows 7 x64

I'm also using a third party odbc library "SQLTools" by PerfectSync - but I don't think thats making the message because I also use it with MySQL with no problems

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue, except I'm just trying to do a simple insert.

Comment: Sorry, I never did find a solution. In the end I switched to using the postgres DLL directly and it wasn't an issue anymore. Look for libpq++. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Are u updating cursor's elements directly?

in this case warning message is informing u that u are changin' cursor's elements while it's open.

Something similar happens, in java language when tryng to change list's elements number (adding or removing elements) while iterating it.

Comment: I am not knowingly using any cursors at all. Im currently making an import program which only uses prepared insert statements and selects nextval of sequences.

Comment: sorry, i supposed it cause warning says: cursor updatability changed

Comment: @berkeleybross just a note: check out RETURNING keyword in postgres SELECT statement, might help to save your time on selecting nextvals..

Comment: @ertx thanks for pointing that out, looks useful. I had been missing MySQLs last_insert_id and it looks like INSERT RETURNING fills the gap ^_^